# How to write different comment-based Help syntax?

Tags: powershell

I would like my module functions to have different syntax showed with `Get-Help` cmdlet.

For example, with `New-Item`:

```
PS> Get-Help New-Item

NAME
    New-Item

SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new item.


SYNTAX
    New-Item [[-Path] ] [-Confirm] [-Credential ] [-Force] [-ItemType ] -Name 
    [-UseTransaction] [-Value ] [-WhatIf] []

    New-Item [-Path]  [-Confirm] [-Credential ] [-Force] [-ItemType ]
    [-UseTransaction] [-Value ] [-WhatIf] []
```

As you can see, in the **SYNTAX** part, there are 2  forms written for the same command.
I would like to have the same thing with my own functions:

```
PS> Get-Help MyFunction

SYNTAX
    MyFunction [-Param1] [-Param3] []

    MyFunction [-Param2] [-Param3] []
```

The **SYNTAX** part is supposed to be automatically generated, but I have already tried to use external MAML help file, using Sapien PowerShell HelpWriter or by hand, both without success. By hand is too much time consuming if it is the only solution, but at least I will have my answer.

I am working on PowerShell 5.1

Comment: The various syntax differences are based on the `ParameterSetName` attributes from `Parameter` and `CmdletBinding`.  If you're not using them, you won't get the output in your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here:

```bsh
function MyFunction {
    <#
    comment-based Help
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='First')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='First')]
        [switch]$Param1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Second')]
        [switch]$Param2,

        [switch]$Param3
    )
...
}
```

Then, using `Get-Help` I have my expected result:

```bsh
PS> Get-Help MyFunction

SYNTAX
    MyFunction [-Param1] [-Param3] []

    MyFunction [-Param2] [-Param3] []
```